# Is this a good way of setting up a Page that displays team member/staff

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have simple wordpress site that mainly consists of "Pages". One of the "Pages" is called "Our team" and is located http://www.examplewebsite.com/about/our-team.

The "Our team" need to display team members with their names, role, description, photo, etc.

My idea is to set up a "Custom Post Type" called Team with custom fields to capture name, role, photo etc (using http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ to create custom fields).

Then creating a Custom Page Template (http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) which pulls in data from the "Team" custom post entries and apply this "custom template" to /about/our-team "Page" using the "Template" option on right hand side that appears when editing a "Page".

Question: is above a good way to set-up? If not, can you suggest an alternative please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the custom post is pretty much the way to go for something like a "Team" page where you are likely to have many Team member specific fields like `Title`, `LinkedIn Profile`, `Social Profile`, `Photo` etc etc.

In fact many examples that try to show the use of Custom Post Types in Wordpress use this "Team" use-case for showcasing this feature.

Here's a nice example: [Creating a "Meet The Team" Page in WordPress](http://css-tricks.com/creating-meet-team-page-wordpress/).

You maybe able to reuse some of that code for your own purposes too.

[image]